# How to replace string between two string with the same length

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input string like this:

```
ABCDEFG[HIJKLMN]OPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

How can I replace each character in the string between the `[]` with an `X` (resulting in the same number of `X`s as there were characters)?

For example, with the input above, I would like an output of:

```
ABCDEFG[XXXXXXX]OPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

---

I am using JavaScript's RegEx for this and would prefer if answers could be an implementation that does this using JavaScript's RegEx Replace function.

---

I am new to RegEx so please explain what you do and (if possible) link articles to where I can get further help.

Comment: With the latest ECMAScript 2018, you may do that easily. If you need to target other environments, it is also easy, but requires a bit of code.

Comment: I will run in javascript,can you tell the code?

Answer (score 2):

Using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and passing the match to a [function as parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), and then `Array(m.length).join("X")` to generate the **X**'s needed:

```js
var str = "ABCDEFG[HIJKLMN]OPQRSTUVWXYZ"

str = str.replace(/\[[A-Z]*\]/g,(m)=>"["+Array(m.length-1).join("X")+"]")

console.log(str);
```

We could use also `.*` instead of `[A-Z]` in the regex to match any character.

About regular expressions there are thousands of resources, specifically in JavaScript, you could see [Regular Expressions MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) but the best way to learn, in my opinion, is practicing, I find [regex101](https://regex101.com/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str="ABCDEFG[HIJKLMN]OPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const run=str=>str.replace(/\[.*]/,(a,b,c)=>c=a.replace(/[^\[\]]/g,x=>x="X"));
console.log(run(str));
```

The first pattern `/\[.*]/` is to select letters inside bracket [] and the second pattern `/[^\[\]]/` is to replace the letters to "X"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to replace a string between two square brackets:

```
const rxp = /\[.*?\]/g;
"ABCDEFG[HIJKLMN]OPQRSTUVWXYZ".replace(rxp, (x) => {
    return x.replace(rxp, "X".repeat(x.length)-2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can observe that every individual letter you wish to match is followed by a series of zero or more non-'[' characters, until a ']' is found. This is quite simple to express in JavaScript-friendly regex:

```
/[A-Z](?=[^\[]*\])/g
```

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/0gBGQ8/1/)

`(?= )` is a "positive lookahead assertion"; it peeks ahead of the current matching point, without consuming characters, to verify its contents are matched. In this case, "[^[]*]" matches exactly what I described above.

Now you can substitute each [A-Z] matched with a single 'X'.